# Active Deployment Configuration: No Activation Skipping deployment step because a pre-deployment command is not specified

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, deployment

When I deploy my SharePoint solution I get

> Active Deployment Configuration: No Activation Skipping deployment
>   step because a pre-deployment command is not specified.

in my output window and waiting for long time without moving ahead.

Have anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: are you using PowerShell of VS to deploy?

Comment: Doing VS deployment

Comment: try the deployment step with powershell! must be a multi-server farm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your project in Visual Studio, right click on the project name and click on **Properties**. From there choose the **SharePoint** tab and in the **Active Deployment Configuration** choose **No Activation**.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the work around**

GO to the **Central** **administrator > System Settings > Manage farm solution**

Select the features that you are deploying . Then click deploy.

After that go to site setting, site features and activate the features. (you will now be able to access the feature)

That is to mean the feature is deployed but not activated!